# javascript - do the opposite of a regex split

Tags: javascript

I have a string like so:

```
var string = "{{ \"Foo {0}\" | i18n:[\"Bar\"] }}";
```

What I want are the values in the quotes, which I can achieve with a regex `/".*?"/`.

But when I do this with sprint, it doesn't return what's in the quotes, but everything outside of them.

```
string.split(/".*?"/);
```

**Returns**

```
[ '{{ ', ' | i18n }}' ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use [.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

You want to capture things inside quotes, so you'll add a capturing expression.

```
var exp = /"(.*?)"/;
string.match(exp);
```

Comment: Yeah, I just figured that out as soon as you posted.  :P I will mark correct.  Thanks!

Comment: `.match` seems to be stopping at the first occurrance of the matched expression.  Any way to make it continue through the entire string?

Comment: use the global flag in your expression `/"(.*?)"/g`